# Angular - Need guide to setup Routing & Navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am a beginner of the Angular.io.

I have created multiple components for content and 1 for the header.

Now I need to create routing, to let user can click on the button and go to the targeted page.

I have gone through the documentation but unfortunately, I cannot understand.

Does anyone have a quick tutorial to teach me how to set it up? Or can share the steps here. Doesn't have to be a very advanced tutorial, I just need some clue to start, then I can easily explore more into it.

I have tried to do according to tutorial but it still not working:

in the app.module.ts:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RestaurantsComponent }  from './restaurants/restaurants.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      {
        enableTracing: true, // <-- debugging purposes only
        preloadingStrategy: SelectivePreloadingStrategy,

      }
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'restaurants',
    component: RestaurantsComponent,
  }
];
```

However, when I accessing http://localhost:4200/restaurant, it is not displaying the restaurant component.

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet>`? Do you get an error message? Did you try without specifying a `preloadingStrategy`?

Comment: I have updated my answer with an link to working example on stackblitz. You can show this an try to do something similar in your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `app-routing.module.ts` you should define you routes and import all components, which you need for routing.

[Here is an working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yh8tms).

**Step 1: Create app-routing.module.ts and define the routes**

First import that:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Now create new array for your routes as `const`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'homepage',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'homepage',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

Use this `appRoutes` for module configuration:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Import `HomeComponent` into this file. You should import all component which you will use for routing.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
// after above imports
import { HomeComponent } from './your/path/home.component';
```

Import this `AppRoutingModule` in your `AppModule`.

**Step 2: Add `router-outlet` to app-component**

In first step we have define one route for homepage. For bring it to work, we should add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to our main app component.

Add following code to ypur `app.component.html`:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Now our basic route should work.

**Routing with child routes**

If you will create some routes with their child routes, so you can do this as follow.

Modife your `appRoutes` in `AppRoutingModule`:

Example: We create an community main page with following child pages:

- Community

  - Forum
  - Documentation
  - Contribute

Here is our extended appRoutes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'homepage',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'homepage',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'community',
    component: CommunityComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'forum',
        component: ForumComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'documentation',
        component: DocumentationComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'contribute',
        component: ContributeComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Import components our new pages.

Now you can access in your app to `homepage` and `community` route. Our `community` route has some children. For accessing child routes we should add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to our `community.component.html`. After adding this, all child routes should work.

Remember: If you have child routes, than you should add router-outlet to the template of parent route.

[Here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) is an good tutorial from angular.io page.

Answer (score 1):

Your path is 'restaurants' while you are trying to access 'restaurant' (without 's')